# MongoDB - Group Across Two Fields & Then Group On Remaining Third Field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB (via Mongoose with a NodeJS/Express backend) and have a data structure where I first need to group by two fields, and then once grouped at that level, then group by a third field in the database.

My data structure is as follows (cut down for simplicity):

```
{
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "5000",
   model: "5900x",
   userRating: 5
},
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "5000",
   model: "5900x",
   userRating: 2
},
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "5000",
   model: "5600x",
   userRating: 3
},
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "3000",
   model: "3900x",
   userRating: 5
},
{
   brand: "Intel",
   series: "i9",
   model: "12900k",
   userRating: 5
},
{
   brand: "Intel",
   series: "i9",
   model: "12900k",
   userRating: 4
}
}
```

As you will note the individual CPU model can repeat multiple times.

As a result, what I am trying to do is as follows:

1. Group by BOTH `brand` and `series`
2. Once grouped by `brand` and `series`, then group at the individual `model` level and average the `userRating` of that model.

Therefore the desired end result of the data is as follows

```
{
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "5000",
   data: [
      {
       model: "5900x"
       avgRating: 3.5
      },
      {
      model: "5600x"
       avgRating: 3
      }      
      ]
},
{
   brand: "AMD",
   series: "3000",
   data: [
      {
       model: "3900x"
       avgRating: 5
      } 
      ]
},
{
   brand: "Intel",
   series: "i9",
   data: [
      {
       model: "12900k"
       avgRating: 4.5
      } 
      ]
}

}
```

I have tried 100 and one ways to try and get this to work but I am still stumped.

The closest I have managed to get so far on the back of 2 nights looking at this is as follows:

```
const aggregate = await CpuReviews.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            groupId: { series: "$series", brand: "$brand" },
            model: "$model",
            userRating: { $avg: "$userRating" },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id.groupId",
          data: {
            $push: {
              model: "$_id.model",
              userRating: { $avg: "$_id.userRating" },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

This ends up in a data structure like this:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "series": "3000",
            "brand": "amd"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "model": "Ryzen 9 3950X",
                "userRating": 5678
            }
        ]
    },
```

I have also tried using `$project` to rework the data but couldn't take what I have above and get it any closer (I'd typically get thrown an internal server error).

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide on where I am going wrong and how to get back to the right path.

Comment: The order of the fields by which are used for grouping matter. series+brand and brand+series are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have grouped by all the fields, correct as below,

- `$group` by `series`, `brand`, and `model` fields and get average
- `$group` by `series` and `brand` fields and construct the `data` array with `model` and average field
- `$project` to show required fields and format the result

```
const aggregate = await CpuReviews.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        series: "$series",
        brand: "$brand",
        model: "$model"
      },
      avgRating: { $avg: "$userRating" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        series: "$_id.series",
        brand: "$_id.brand"
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          model: "$_id.model",
          avgRating: "$avgRating"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      series: "$_id.series",
      brand: "$_id.brand",
      data: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0pshb4BznYC)